# Use Custom_Pipe in TS

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I have this pipe:

```
@Pipe({
name: 'searchNomES'
})
export class SearchNomESPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(uos: IUo[], name?: string,): IUo[] {

if (!uos) return [];
if (!name) return uos;
name = name.toLocaleLowerCase();
uos = [...uos.filter(uo => uo.nom.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(name))];
   return uos;

}
}
```

It works fine when I use the pipe in my html like that:

```
<ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let image of display | async | searchNomES : name " >
</ng-container>
```

But I try to use the pipe in my component.ts. I try this:

```
<mat-form-field >
<input matInput  
(keyup)="applyFilter2($event.target.value)">    
</mat-form-field>

import { SearchNomESPipe } from '../../search-nomES.pipe';

constructor(private  espipe:  SearchNomESPipe) { }

ngOnInit() {this.display=this.markerservice.getGeos() }

applyFilter2(name : string) {
this.display = this.espipe.transform(this.display,name);
}
```

My service:

```
getGeos() { return this. 
database.list('ES').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
return actions.map(a => {
const data = a.payload.val();
const key = a.payload.key;
return {key, ...data };
```

But I have this error:

> uos.filter is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: i want use my custom pipe, not in the html but in my ts code.

Comment: When are you calling `applyFilter2`

Comment: when i write in my mat from field (keypup)...

Comment: What does `this.markerservice.getGeos()` return? The error suggests that the result may not be a list.

Comment: it is an angularfirelist. i updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with an observable, therefore your pipe must handle an observable, and return an observable. You will then be using `async` pipe in view. Modify your pipe to:

```
transform(uos: Observable<IUo[]>, name?: string): Observable<IUo[]> {
  return uos.pipe(
    map(data => {
      if (!data || !name) return [];
      name = name.toLocaleLowerCase();
      return data.filter(uo => uo.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(name));
    })
  );
}
```

Then template:

```
<ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let image of filtered | async" >
```

TS:

```
display: Observable<IUo[]>;
filtered: Observable<IUo[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.display=this.markerservice.getGeos() 
}

applyFilter2(name : string) {
   this.filtered = this.espipe.transform(this.display,name);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-33tnzj?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: thanks it works ! how i can filter with a service ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are talking about something like... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkuiaj?file=src/app/app.component.ts I caution you again, be careful with these impure pipe. If your app becomes slow, it can be caused of this pipe.

Comment: or do you mean that you want to try having a function in service to filter instead of using a pipe?

Comment: Actually, now when really thinking, as long as you are using the pipe **only** in TS file, it will not affect performance. I guess I'm tired and not thinking properly, haha :D The issue only is in if you provide the pipe in the template, since it would be called often. Now it's only called when input changes. So you are all good doing it like I provided in answer! :)

Comment: I had much better performance when the pipe only affected the model. Now in the component, I have slowdowns. I will move towards filtering by service

Comment: hmm... I wonder. Moving the filtering to service, means just moving the code from the pipe to a function in the service, and that function does exactly what the pipe does. You could add a debounceTime to the function, so that it won't be called on each keystroke. I added a debouncetime and console log in the pipe, so you can see that it's not called that more often than a "normal" function does: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15yoxh?file=src/app/app.component.ts. But sure, try with service.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.markerservice.getGeos().subscribe(resp: any[] => {
      this.display = this.espipe.transform(resp, name)
    })
  }
```